# How to parse Javascript object in redis lua script

Tags: lua, redis, eval, node-redis

I am using node_redis npm package to call lua function. I want to pass javascript object to lua.

Below is sample json object:

```
var feeds=[];
var feed ={};
feed.uId ="Zqr6jfu6pgqNpAKaf";
feed.kIds =[];
feed.kIds.push("2557f730-e7a9-11e6-a2e7-49a45a663faf");
feed.kIds.push("224ec110-f9cc-11e6-8f0c-cb2069561ad8");
feeds.push(feed);
```

I am calling eval function to execute my lua script:

```
client.eval(
scriptId, //lua source
0,
feeds,
function(err, result) {  
console.log(err+'------------'+result);
}
);
```

In Lua How I can parse this object to insert all kIds in sorted set key of feed.UId ??

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different languages, you'd have to implement some interface using the low level commands of their respective VMs.

Alternatively, you could convert your object to text and eval it in lua, there seems to be [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2lua) for that already. String eval is a slow operation, however.